# If $f$ belongs to $M^{+} $ and $c \ge 0$ then $cf$ belongs to $M^{+}$ and $ \int cf = c\int f$

Tags: measure-theory

If $f$ belongs to $M^{+} $ and $c \ge 0$ then $cf$ belongs to $M^{+}$ and $\int cf = c\int f$.

I need to proove that, using the following observation:

if $f\in M^{+}$ and $ c>0 $, then the mapping $\varphi \rightarrow \psi = c\varphi$ is a one-toone mapping between simple function $\varphi \in M^{+}$ with $ \varphi \le f $ and simple functions $\varphi$ in $ M^{+} $ with $ \psi \le cf $.

I know that this question is already answer here:[One-to-one mapping of simple functions $\phi \to \psi = c\,\phi$ implies $\int cf\,d\mu = c \int f\,d\mu$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463930/one-to-one-mapping-of-simple-functions-phi-to-psi-c-phi-implies-int-c)

But I can't follow the verbal explanation.

My original idea was to proove $$ c \int f \le \int cf \le c\int f $$
 But I can't... some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be an arbitrary collection of non-negative real numbers. We always have that $\sup_{x\in X}\{cx\}=c\sup_{x\in X}\{x\}$, and $\sup_{x\in X}\{cx\}=\sup_{x\in cX}\{x\}$. Using this fact we can prove this statement quite simply, provided you've already proven the integral equality for simple functions.

A simple function $\varphi$ satisfies $\varphi\leq f$ if and only if there exists another simple function $\psi$ (given by your one-to-one correspondence) satisfying $\psi\leq cf$. Hence
$$c\int f=c\sup_{\varphi\leq f}\left\{\int\varphi\right\}=\sup_{\varphi\leq f}\left\{\int c\varphi\right\}=\sup_{\psi\leq cf}\left\{\int\psi\right\}=\int cf.$$

Comment: That is fine but should not be one-one correspondence and also onto, i.e. also surjective to be exact?

Comment: @MarcoBellocchi Yes, one-to-one correspondence here means that the map is bijective. The inverse is simply $\psi\mapsto c^{-1}\psi$

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, that is what I thought, very kind of you